# Regular Expression to match some strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to find any string from the following set of strings from the user's input:

- Password@123
- Pa$$w0rd@123
- Password#123
- Pa$$w0rd#123
- Password_123
- Pa$$w0rd_123

The digits at the end should be of the min length 3 & max 6. And this is the regex that I wrote:

```
(Password@(\d{2,6}))|(Pa\$\$w0rd@(\d{2,6}))|(Password#(\d{2,6}))|(Pa\$\$w0rd#(\d{2,6}))|(Password_(\d{2,6}))|(Pa\$\$w0rd_(\d{2,6})).$
```

[I tested my regex on this website and it is not working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htYOL.png)

It shows "test passed" until the no. of digits reaches 8 (which it shouldn't), and that clearly means that I have made some mistake. I am not an expert in writing Regexes as I am new to this. I don't understand where am I making a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should look something like this: `^pa[s5$][s5$]w[o0]rd.\d{3,6}$` I'm not 100% sure on the C# exact syntax though. I've set up a test suite at regex101 to show you how it works.

This will grab any combination of the string you've given along with 3-6 digits at the end.

https://regex101.com/r/1KaJNz/2

Comment: The expression could be simplified, but arguably less readable : https://regex101.com/r/1KaJNz/3/tests

Comment: True enough and a couple people pointed out that using a catchall between the letters and numbers is potentially problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using character sets to simplify your regex.  This way you don't have to repeat the common logic for every permutation, which, of course is the point of a regex in the first place.  With that, I came up with the following:

```
Pa[s\$]{2}w[o0]rd[@#_]\d{3,6}
```

You can also add a `5` into the first character set if you want to allow that, as suggested by @JustinMacArthur.

The problem with the regex given in your answer may have something to do with the `.` at the end which matches any character.  This would let any character come after the numbers (including another number) and it would still match.

Comment: The `{2,6}` should instead be `{3,6}`, other than that, I think your answer is the best as it matches the specifics of what the OP was asking.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Good point.  I've fixed that.  I think that I copied the OP's regular expression to start with but I was still somehow fully aware that it should have been `{3,6}` so I'm not sure how I missed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex. Testing of it looks good:

```
Pa(\$|s){2}w(0|o)rd[@#_]\d{3,6}
```